# PHP CRUD JSON file instead of a database like mysql

Tags: php, json, crud

I'm in a bit of pickle, I received a request to create CRUD app to edit JSON object in an array and upload them. I did a bit of research and came across http://www.taffydb.com/ but it doesn't really fit my requirements.

EDIT: I also came across jtables, but it use mysql, similar to http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud.php but it also uses mysql. Is it possible to skip the database portion and write directly to the JSON file?

As this is a very small JSON file, having a database would seem excessive. I have multiple objects in the JSON array which an external app would read from.

What are the viable options I could go for? Ideally the app needs to Add/Edit/Delete from the browser contents to JSON file.

Currently I'm able to display the data accordingly in tables. My code looks like this:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
$jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Background Image</th>
  <th>Video URL (Link to Video)</th>
  <th>Description of Video</th>
</tr>
  <?php
    foreach ($jsonfile->playlist as $obj) {
      echo '<tr><td>' . $obj->title . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $obj->title_bg . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $obj->link . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $obj->description . '</td></tr>';
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "playlist": [
    {
      "title": "Test title",
      "title_bg": "link/to/image.png",
      "link": "https://www.google.com",
      "description": "This is a test JSON Object"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON file will have multiple objects in the `playlist` array

Comment: This json is invalid!! Try to remove last `,`  at `This is a test JSON Object",`

Comment: Ah apologies! WIll edit it!

Comment: What's your problem? With a combination of the above your script with your code? Implementations in the PHP? Do you want to be able to edit / delete from the browser contents JSON file?

Comment: Add/Edit/Delete from the browser contents to JSON file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because I don't feel like it fits the format of this site as discussed in the [help]. This isn't a site for requesting people to write code for you, nor is it suited to extended discussion on the ways of achieving something. If there's a specifc problem with the code you've written so far, you could write a more focussed question about that.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm sorry that my question came out like that, my intention was to gather some opinions on how to approach this, but it seems like I over complicated a simple issue by overthinking too much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

**test.json**

```
{
    "playlist": [
        {
            "title": "Test title1222212321321321",
            "title_bg": "link\/to\/image.png",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.google.com",
            "description": "This is a test JSON Object"
        }, {
            "title": "sdfdasf",
            "title_bg": "adsfdas",
            "link": "fdasf",
            "description": "dasfdasf"
        }, {
            "title": "This is a title ",
            "title_bg": "This is a title bg",
            "link": "This is a link2",
            "description": "This is a description"
        }
    ]
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
$jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
?>
<a href="http://localhost/test/add.php">Add</a>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Background Image</th>
        <th>Video URL (Link to Video)</th>
        <th>Description of Video</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($jsonfile->playlist as $index => $obj): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $obj->title; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $obj->title_bg; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $obj->link; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $obj->description; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://localhost/test/edit.php?id=<?php echo $index; ?>">Edit</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost/test/delete.php?id=<?php echo $index; ?>">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    $getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $jsonfile = json_decode($getfile, true);
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile["playlist"];
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];
}

if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_POST["id"];
    $getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $all = json_decode($getfile, true);
    $jsonfile = $all["playlist"];
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];

    $post["title"] = isset($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : "";
    $post["title_bg"] = isset($_POST["title_bg"]) ? $_POST["title_bg"] : "";
    $post["link"] = isset($_POST["link"]) ? $_POST["link"] : "";
    $post["description"] = isset($_POST["description"]) ? $_POST["description"] : "";



    if ($jsonfile) {
        unset($all["playlist"][$id]);
        $all["playlist"][$id] = $post;
        $all["playlist"] = array_values($all["playlist"]);
        file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($all));
    }
    header("Location: http://localhost/test/index.php");
}
?>
<?php if (isset($_GET["id"])): ?>
    <form action="http://localhost/test/edit.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["title"] ?>" name="title"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["title_bg"] ?>" name="title_bg"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["link"] ?>" name="link"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["description"] ?>" name="description"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    $all = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $all = json_decode($all, true);
    $jsonfile = $all["playlist"];
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];

    if ($jsonfile) {
        unset($all["playlist"][$id]);
        $all["playlist"] = array_values($all["playlist"]);
        file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($all));
    }
    header("Location: http://localhost/test/index.php");
}
```

**add.php**

```
<form action="http://localhost/test/add.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="title_bg" placeholder="title_bg"/>
    <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="link"/>
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description"/>
    <input type="submit" name="add"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $file = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $data = json_decode($file, true);
    unset($_POST["add"]);
    $data["playlist"] = array_values($data["playlist"]);
    array_push($data["playlist"], $_POST);
    file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($data));
    header("Location: http://localhost/test/index.php");
}
?>
```

To run the script you must specify in each of these files, a file path JSON. You have to also change the address of links to your environment.

Comment: So it is simply adding isset and unset, creating the functions and linking them together?

Comment: Thank you for this